# Добавление в архив. POCO Zip

Tags: c++, zip, poco

Для работы с Zip выбрал POCO-библиотеки. Пытаюсь добавить элементы в архив, добавляется только последний. Я так понимаю, что в существующий архив добавить уже ничего не получится. Неужели только перезапись?

Если кто работал с этими библиотеками, подскажите: прав я или нет?

Comment: Телепаты опять в отпусках, гадать "прав или нет" некому. А вот документация с примерами вполне имеется: https://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html

Comment: Документацию я видел и использовал на практике. Результаты описал. Причём здесь телепаты, если я спрашиваю у тех, кто пользовался?